# NoSQL or SQL for Record Store (I.e Music: vinyl, CD, digital).

Tags: sql, nosql

I'm building a record store shop application and was wondering if I should go the NoSQL way or SQL way. I can technically use an off thyself cart. But I never really liked how carts behaved for music type stores...

The model is something to the likes of...

Release(Title, Price, EP, LP, Main Artist, Description)
   Track(Title, Price, Main Artist, Remix Artist)

Very basic structure and I could add the rest of the fields but you get the point...

Comment: Both will work, but it's all up to you. NoSql is kinda fun :)

Comment: I think you should do an assessment: What are the advantages of using an RDBMS? What are the disadvantages? What are the advantages of using NoSQL? What are the disadvantages? After you got all those facts, you can make an informed decision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a large number of factors which could push the decision either way.

A few of the questions I would be asking myself about my data at the outset are:

How big is my data likely to grow? Should the database hold only what is in stock or all possible available titles on the market? I am assuming your database will have many more tables than the two you mention.

Possible answer: By choosing a NoSQL structure at the outset you may thank yourself for it later having provided the scope for good scalability.

How complex is my data? Is there potential for multivalued columns?

If for example you have an artists table, you may want this table to have a release column where the multivalued realease ID's for that artist are stored for easy cross reference to your releases table. In this case a NoSQL type database such as the multivalue database may be interesting as you can avoid performance damaging joins. As your data grows the data retrieval speed could be better than going the SQL route.

Depending on which SQL database you would select, there is also the cost aspect to look at as well.

If you do go the NoSQL route, then the flexibility this route offers needs to be backed up with a good initial data design from the outset, so that the flexibility does not become your enemy later down the line.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

NoSQL solutions are generally easier to start with, but might be harder to optimize in the future. The freedom you get from lack of data schema might turn around and bite you — you might find yourself with different generations of records with different structures as your application evolves, unless you make extra effort to keep your old records' structure up to date.

SQL solutions generally are more-rigid and require more planning beforehand, but on the other hand they are quite a mature tech, they enforce your data's structure and are specifically designed to keep it consistent.

I would pick SQL in your case, as a record store will have mostly long-lived data, which will benefit from having a stable structure imposed upon it. In my opinion, NoSQL is better suited for applications that handle very short-lived data, where you're not that concerned with old data's integrity and structure (e.g. chats, game scoreboards, etc).